# INT type issue on a prepared Sql Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pivoting SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT    
    [DateTime],[CountryCode],[Value]
  FROM MyDataTable
) MyAlias
PIVOT (
  SUM([Value])
  FOR [CountryCode]
  IN ([GBR],[USA])
) AS PivotTable
```

And I made it dynamic for the CountryCodes using a stored proc like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DynamicPivotTableInSql
  @ListToPivot    NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SqlStatement = N'
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT    
    [DateTime],[CountryCode],[Value]
  FROM MyDataTable
) MyAlias
PIVOT (
  SUM([Value])
  FOR [CountryCode]
  IN ('+@ListToPivot+')
) AS PivotTable';

EXEC(@SqlStatement)
END
```

I tried to introduce an INT variable and although the procedure creates, I keep getting an error:

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DynamicPivotTableInSql
  @ListToPivot    NVARCHAR(255),
  @WhereParam     INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SqlStatement = N'
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT    
    [DateTime],[CountryCode],[Value]
  FROM MyDataTable
  WHERE SomeColumn = '+@WhereParam+'
) MyAlias
PIVOT (
  SUM([Value])
  FOR [CountryCode]
  IN ('+@ListToPivot+')
) AS PivotTable';

EXEC(@SqlStatement)
END
```

I tried putting in `CONVERT(int,'+@WhereParam+')` to no avail - is there a way to include ints in the `NVARCHAR` sql statement??

Comment: The above isn't a dynamic statement though, just a malformed one.

Comment: As for parametrising, this is why you *don't* use the syntax `EXEC(@SQL)`; use `sys.sp_executesql` as you *can* parametrise then.

Comment: What you posted isn't a dynamic query, it's a proper query that tries to match the strings `+@WhereParam+'` and `'+@ListToPivot+'`. Finally, `Exec` is trying to execute an empty string, because nothing was assigned to `@SqlStatement`

Comment: You declare `@SqlStatement` but you don't assign anything to it, your SQL statement is not dynamic, SQL server just sees a string that's an incorrect data type.

Comment: `IN` expects a list of values. `IN ('+@ListToPivot+')` has a single value, `+@ListToPivot+'`. You *can't* treat a string with numbers as if it was a list of numbers.

Comment: Edited the question to include the line where `SqlStatement` is assigned - copy/paste error. Also the `@ListToPivot` receives a string list - that's not the issue, it's the INT param `@WhereParam` that's causing the issue.

Comment: `' + cast(@WhereParam as nvarchar(20)) + N'`

Answer (score 0):

Don't **inject** your parameters, *parametrise* them. You `WHERE` should be parametrised:

```sql
WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeColumn
```

And then *don't* use `EXEC(@SQL)` syntax because you can't parametrise it. Use `sys.sp_executesql`:

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SqlStatement, N'@SomeColumn int', @WhereParam;
```